# Sharepoint Designer - Get a string separated by comma

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am getting values from Sharepoint Workflow 2013 and I need to verify if a specific value is included in my values that are coming from workflow.

For example, **these values**:
Group 1, Group 2, Group 3

These are my values that are coming from workflow. I need to verify if the value Group 2 is on **these values**.

How can I do this in Sharepoint Designer's workflow? The workflow's version is 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Find Substring in String](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-string-actions.htm#findsubstringinstring) action, which will return the index if found.

Here's an example of how it can be used.

[SharePoint Designer 2013: Find Substring in String Action](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-designer-2013-find-substring-in-string-action)